# Permission denied when using git bash

Tags: git, permissions, git-bash

I would want to know what is this Git error at the start of Git bash ?

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/dev/mqueue': Permission denied
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/mtab': Permission denied
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts' -> '/etc/hosts'
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/hosts': Permission denied
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\protocol' -> '/etc/protocols'
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/protocols': Permission denied
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\services' -> '/etc/services'
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/services': Permission denied
'C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\networks' -> '/etc/networks'
/usr/bin/cp: cannot create regular file '/etc/networks': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/etc/post-install/01-devices.post': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/etc/post-install/03-mtab.post': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/etc/post-install/06-windows-files.post': Permission denied
rm: cannot remove '/etc/post-install/99-post-install-cleanup.post': Permission denied
```

Comment: What has this got to do with CMD or SYSTEM32.

Comment: This error is showing me on Gitbash

Comment: Do the errors occur if you run Gitbash as Administrator?

Answer (score 44):

See https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/1449. This happens when the post-install scripts fail to run for some reason.

Running Git Bash as administrator once triggers execution of those scripts and fixes the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this happened to me after downloading Git for Windows 2.29.0, post-install scripts failed, and running it as admin once allows the `chmod` command to work and permanently fixes the problem! I would like to add: this may happen to every update that Git Bash has; you just have to occasionally run Git as administrator (right after finishing update) for the scripts to run!

Answer (score 4):

Try to log in as admin in your bash to see if that solves your problem!

Comment: Why must Git Bash be run with elevated privileges now? It didn't require this in the past

Answer (score 0):

i installed git to VM linux, then i switched to my windows10 then i run the git bash,
I have the same problem, then i run git bash as admin, and it fixed!