# Git clone, Permission denied on windows

Tags: windows, git-bash, visual-studio-power-tools

Im trying to clone a repo and facing `Permission denied` error as below

```
$ git clone https://github.com/PowerShellEmpire/PowerTools.git
bash: /mingw64/bin/git: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running git-bash as administrator (right-click > run as administrator), so that it fixes the permissions on the executable files in /mingw64/bin.
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62390205/13339621

Comment: Yes i was trying use administrator privileges on git bash.